# Failing TravisCI due to rJava

Tags: r, travis-ci, cran, rjava

## Summary

TravisCI build suddenly fails, possibly due to some rJava shenanigans. Local checks (Linux) are squeaky-clean.

## Preamble

My package was building fine on Travis up until 2 months ago, [this](https://travis-ci.org/github/ocbe-uio/DIscBIO/builds/721646083/config) is the last successful build.

The next build only changed some minor things on README.md (which is even on .Rbuildignore), but TravisCI started failing anyway. This makes me think that all I need to do is adjust .travis.yml accordingly. I've tried every tweak I could find ([here](https://github.com/ocbe-uio/DIscBIO/commits/fix-travis/.travis.yml)'s the commit history of the file).

## How far I got

The best I could manage so far is to narrow down the error to either this:

> The command "sudo R CMD javareconf" failed and exited with 1 during .

or this:

> checking whether JNI programs run... configure: error: Unable to run a simple JNI program. Make sure you have configured R with Java support (see R documentation) and check config.log for failure reason.
>
> Error in system(cmd) : (converted from warning) error in running command
>
> - removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava’
>
> Error in i.p(...) :
>
> (converted from warning) installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
>
> Calls:  ... with_rprofile_user -> with_envvar -> force -> force -> i.p
>
> Execution halted
>
> The command "Rscript -e 'deps <- remotes::dev_package_deps(dependencies = >NA);remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% >installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, >installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 >during .

The full log of both errors can be found [here](https://travis-ci.org/github/ocbe-uio/DIscBIO/builds/741644704) and [here](https://travis-ci.org/github/ocbe-uio/DIscBIO/jobs/741629893), respectively.